# How to create a logout route when working with passport-jwt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, mern

I'm trying to follow a tutorial and code along to learn more about authentication using passport-jwt and mern stack from this blog tutorial: https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-authentication-mern-node-passport-express-mongo/. When I login using the username and password, it gives me a token. And using that token, when I try to logout using the logic below. I get the error: `TypeError: user.refreshToken.id(...).remove is not a function`.

I don't understand how to fix the problem.

```
router.get("/logout", verifyUser, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { signedCookies = {} } = req;
  const { refreshToken } = signedCookies;
  User.findById(req.user._id).then((user) => {
    const tokenIndex = user.refreshToken.findIndex(
      (item) => item.refreshToken === refreshToken
    );

    if (tokenIndex !== -1) {
      user.refreshToken.id(user.refreshToken[tokenIndex]._id).remove()
    }

    try {
      user.save();
      res.clearCookie("refreshToken", COOKIE_OPTIONS);
      res.send({ success: true, user: user.refreshToken._id })
    } catch (error) {
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.send(error)
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "TypeError: user.refreshToken.id(...).remove is not a function" is usually caused when you try to call the remove() method on a non-existent or invalid object.

In your code, the issue might be caused by the fact that the user.refreshToken array is empty, or it does not contain the expected refreshToken object. You can check if user.refreshToken is not empty before calling the remove() method.

Here is a modified version of your code that includes error handling and checks for the user.refreshToken array:

```
router.get("/logout", verifyUser, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { signedCookies = {} } = req;
  const { refreshToken } = signedCookies;
  const userId = req.user._id;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }
    const tokenIndex = user.refreshToken.findIndex(
      (item) => item.refreshToken === refreshToken
    );
    if (tokenIndex === -1) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid refresh token" });
    }
    user.refreshToken.id(user.refreshToken[tokenIndex]._id).remove();
    await user.save();
    res.clearCookie("refreshToken", COOKIE_OPTIONS);
    res.send({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
});
```

In this modified version, we added error handling for cases where the user is not found or the refreshToken is invalid. We also used await with the User.findById() and user.save() methods to handle asynchronous operations more elegantly.

Comment: I tried using your code. But it gives this error `TypeError: user.refreshToken.id(...).remove is not a function`

Comment: I tried console logging `console.log(user.refreshToken.id(user.refreshToken[tokenIndex]))` and it gave the this: `{
  refreshToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NDE1YTlmY2UzYjRhOWNiODQ5MWJlZmMiLCJpYXQiOjE2NzkxNjM3NDAsImV4cCI6MTY4MTc1NTc0MH0.UKE_OLQ4W4cgQfrR1nRIbFFPR1k-DClLwhH_yIfDudk',
  _id: new ObjectId("6416015c3aed2e26a3e0b17f")
}`

Comment: Is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

The line with `.remove` is wrong. Replace it entirely with:

```js
user.refreshToken.splice(tokenIndex, 1)
```

By the way, this is in response to the original block of code.